# Show big text in qml

Tags: qt, qml

Trying to display a text file in qml. The file size is about 3 megabytes. At the same time there are:

- long opening of the form,
- large waste of memory.

Tried use ScrollView, Flickable, Text and TextArea. How can these problems be avoided?

QML

```
ScrollView {
    id: idScrollView
    anchors {
        fill: parent
        margins: Dimensions.x(15)
    }
    Text {
        id: idContent
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: Dimensions.x(20)
        }
        text: viewmodel.getLogText()
        font.pixelSize: Dimensions.y(10)
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    }
}
```

C++

```
QString MainViewModel::getLogText()
{
    const int maxSz = 1024 * 200;
    QString result;
    QFile file(ALog::filePath());
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        if (file.size() > maxSz)
            file.seek(file.size() - maxSz);
        QByteArray arr = file.read(maxSz);
        result = QString::fromLatin1(arr);
        if (file.size() > maxSz)
            result = QString("Skip %1  Kb\n\n").arg((file.size() - maxSz)/1024) + result;
        file.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just use [TextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html) in `readOnly` mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: Try to put the file in the resource file or to open it from FS. May be the problem is long loading, not long rendering. What is `viewmodel`?

Comment: can you provide code of `viewmodel`? Also you should use [textDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) to achieve improvement. You can also move process of loading document to side tread - details of code needed.

Comment: Checked, getLogText function works very quickly. Added its current content. Now is given only 200 kilobytes of text. But it has a delay in opening and increase memory by about 70 megabytes (according to Windows Manager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a partial solution. It loads much faster and consumes several times less memory. Among the disadvantages-there is no possibility to convert Text to TextArea to be able to select the text to copy to the clipboard.

```
property variant stringList: null

function updateText() {
    stringList = viewmodel.getLogText().split('\n')
    idContentListView.positionViewAtEnd()
}

ListView {
    id: idContentListView
    model: stringList
    anchors {
        fill: parent
        margins: Dimensions.x(15)
    }
    delegate: Text {
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        text: model.modelData
        font.pixelSize: Dimensions.y(10)
        textFormat: Text.PlainText
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    }
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
}
```

Comment: As is, this doesn't seem to work. @op, any chance you could post a full working example?